# Error: Unable to parse the provided SSML. The provided text is not valid SSML

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo, ssml

I am receiving this error when using the `Test` section of the Alexa Developer portal website

> Error: Unable to parse the provided SSML. The provided text is not valid SSML.

The error occurs after I get a successful response and I press the listen button.

the response output is:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "text": "Here are some recent stories about siemens:Citigroup Inc. Reaffirms Buy Rating for Siemens AG (SIE)Siemens AG (SIE) Rating Reiterated by Citigroup Inc.Global Hydrophone Market Report 2014-2021 - Analysis, Technologies & Forecasts - Vendors: Siemens, Sensor Technology, Cetacean Research Technology - Research and MarketsSiemens Bags The 2016 Frost & Sullivan Asia-Pacific Building Technologies Company Of The Year Award"
    },
    "reprompt": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "type": "PlainText",
        "text": "What else can I help with?"
      }
    },
    "shouldEndSession": false
  },
  "sessionAttributes": {}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so seems alexa doesn't like the special character `&` in the text parameter of the outputSpeech response. I replaced it with the word `and` and that resolved my issue.

Comment: Good find. Nice helpful error message from Amazon there. Not!

Comment: Hi Vik thx for figuring this out.  I also had this issue & your question solved this for me. Good Job!

Comment: Ah, this was my problem as well! I wish we didn't have to guess what it likes and what it doesn't like!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"outputSpeech": {
          "ssml": "<speak>your test here</speak>",
          "type": "SSML",
        },
```

Comment: You should make some effort and provide some background as to why this snippet solves the problem...